# installing flask-mysql using conda

Tags: python, mysql, macos, flask, conda

How should I install flask-mysql using conda?

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:flask_app mona$ conda install -c auto flask-mysql
Fetching package metadata .............

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - flask-mysql

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/auto/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/auto/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

I can install it using pip but I wonder if there's a hack to install it using conda as well:

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:flask_app mona$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
Monas-MacBook-Pro:flask_app mona$ pip install flask-mysql
```

Comment: it seems conda's flask-mysql only available for linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that if you install with `pip install flask-mysql`, you will be able to import the package from within your flask environment (after the source activate command). There is no working conda install package for it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `flask-mysql` using the command `conda install -c auto flask-mysql` is currently only supported by Linux. If you check this [link](https://anaconda.org/auto/flask-mysql), you'll find this package is only available for linux-32 and linux-64

I am assuming you want to install a database toolkit for Flask. May I suggest you use **SQLAlchemy**? 
It supports MySQL starting with version 4.1 through modern releases. Follow this link for more details: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html

The conda command to install Flask and SQLAlchemy is:

```
conda install -c conda-forge flask-sqlalchemy
```

Or, to get python + flask + mysql working on Mac you can simply type in these commands:

```
pip install flask
```

Then,

```
sudo su
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
pip install MySQL-python
```

Finally, make a symlink

```
cd /usr/local
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I am using mysql! pip worked because it is linked to my Anaconda Python

Comment: Hi @MonaJalal , Anaconda does not have the package that you're looking for. Why not fall back on pip install or try searching using a binstar package. Run conda install binstar and search for the appropriate package to look for and then conda install -c a matching package. Let me know if that solves your problem!